# Merge Local Repositories using GIT-TFS

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I have two local repositories. Let's say REPO-A and REPO-B. REPO-B is an updated version of REPO-A provided by an outside vendor. REPO-A is managed using GIT-TFS and REPO-B was a GIT repo. I created a VS project for REPO-B but now I want to merge the new source files of REPO-B (which are the same) with REPO-A. Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

When you say REPO-B is an updated version of REPO-A, I assume it's a copy of the original git repo, and that it shares the same original commit history?

If so, you should be able to add REPO-B as a remote for REPO-A, fetch the changes from B and then merge them in.

Comment: yes once you fetched from the remote created, you will have to use `git rebase --into`...